# How to calculate $r<r_{c} $?

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, biology

For the following question, I am getting that the Fixed points are u=0 and $u_{+/-}=(1/r +/- \sqrt(1/r^2 -4))/2 $. Then I see that $u_{+/-} $ is real for r^2<1/4 => r>1/2. In this evaluation I am not sure where to get the value $r_{c} $ from as required in the underlined bit of the text.

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Seems almost correct:  $r<1/2$.  You should also notice that $$u_-=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4r^2}}{2r}$$ is positive, since $1 > \sqrt{1-4r^2}$.